# AngularJS: when creating a new directive, why there is a controller?

Tags: angularjs

To my understanding, controller is responsible for preparing the model, and pass the model to the directive which is responsible for updating DOM.
So when creating a new directive, why there is a controller inside?
Does this mean that I can do something like connecting server inside a directive?

```js
app.directive('hover', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            // what is the controller for?
            ...
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: did you try read official documentation?

Comment: If the request to connect to a server is encapsulated inside an Angular [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), you are able to inject that service into the directive and to subsequently call it.

Comment: Read the section **Creating Directives that Communicate** @ http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs on `$compile` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile):

> ### `controller`
>
> […] The controller is instantiated before
>   the pre-linking phase and it is shared with other directives (see
>   `require` attribute). This allows the directives to communicate with
>   each other and augment each other's behavior. The controller is
>   injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the following locals:
>
> - `$scope` - Current scope associated with the element
> - `$element` - Current element
> - `$attrs` - Current attributes object for the element
> - `$transclude` - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope. The scope can be overridden by an optional first argument.
>     `function([scope], cloneLinkingFn)`.